# Oracle 11g PGA advice view is empty when it shouldn't

Tags: optimization, oracle-11g, memory, configuration, performance, performance-tuning

I have the following situation in an Oracle 11g server (it's part of a RAC). `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` is set, `STATISTICS_LEVEL` is `TYPICAL`, and yet `V$PGA_TARGET_ADVICE` shows up empty. Why does this happen?

Also, the `'maximum PGA allocated'` parameter, being more than `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET`, seems to indicate there's room for tuning. Correct?

```
SQL> show parameter STATISTICS_LEVEL

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
statistics_level                     string      TYPICAL

SQL> select * from V$PGA_TARGET_ADVICE;

no rows selected

SQL> show parameter PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 23G

SQL> select * from V$PGASTAT where name='maximum PGA allocated';

NAME                                                                  VALUE UNIT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- ------------
maximum PGA allocated                                            3.6542E+10 bytes

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bug 11872813** - V$PGA_TARGET_ADVICE VIEW IS EMPTY.

> After setting PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET > approximately 12G the
>   V$PGA_TARGET_ADVICE view is empty.
>   This issue will be fixed in version 12.1 and a fix is expected to be included  in patch set
>   11.2.0.4.
>
> Apply Patch 11872813